# How to use a Web Inspector with emulated android device (AVD)

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, web-inspector

I have the Android SDK downloaded (on a mac), and no access to Android hardware. I can start up AVD and emulate various android devices fine, but I have some CSS I'd like to inspect in the Android browser on said emulated devices. I just can't figure out how to do this.

For iOS you can hook up Safari to the xcode emulator super easy, but I can't seem to figure out the equivalent for Android and Chrome. All of the tutorials I find on the topic tell you to use a meatspace device connected through USB! Doesn't even need to be chrome - any web inspector-like service at this point, that lets me see and change CSS on the fly, will do. Help!

Answer (score 7):

**Easy Peasy:**

1. Start the Android Emulator (e.g. by running your project in Android Studio)
2. Start Google Chrome and visit [chrome://inspect](http://chrome://inspect)
3. Click the Inspect-link below the detected Emulator, and off you go!

Comment: I think it's important to mention that you start Google Chrome on your desktop and visit chrome://inspect and then select the AVD from the list.Visiting chrome://inspect within the emulator won't work.